# can't get latitude and longitude by gps or network

Tags: android, gps

I  am trying to fetch GPS latitude and longitude on a mobile device. there is no error in log but I can't get any information. not matter if "use wireless networks/GPS" setting is selected or not.need help

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final static String TAG = "GPSTest";

    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private LocationListener mLocationListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        String serviceName = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(serviceName);

        mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged");
                if (location != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Current Latitude = " + location.getLatitude());
                    Log.e(TAG, "Current Longitude = " + location.getLongitude());
                }
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled");

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged");
            }
        };

        if (!mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, mLocationListener);
        } else {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, mLocationListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually using in a Device? If you are using in the emulator you'll have to force 
(`geo fix <longitude value> <latitude value>`) through Telnet. In the device you'll have to activate location services in Settings.

Other thing, do you have the following line/lines in the manifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
```

You will need permission to be able to access the location.

**EDIT**

You can also use DDMS to simulate Geo location on the emulator.

Comment: emulator is not good enough because when I send a location infomation with location control the emulator will restart…… when I test this in a mobile，there isn't any reaction or log.so，I think there may be something wrong in my code and I haven't know it.

Comment: permissions are provided . I also test it with a app which can give a fake GPS info，no difference.

Comment: You've probably tried this, but you could make some breakpoints when you're setting the "requestLocation" on the Location Manager, see which one he is using, and checking if anything is failing.

You should ensure that Network Provider is enabled in Settings before actually requesting it, like you do in the GPS Provider. Maybe GPS isn't enabled and he jumps to the 'else" and Network isn't also enabled.

Comment: both enabled. there isn't any log in onLocationChanged(),neither is  getLastKnowLocation() ,the Location always be null, I don't know why

Comment: What is the version of the Android OS ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you provided the permissions in your manifest file as below :

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Please give these permissions:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and for more browse this link:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/